# how to change file suffixes in a makefile?

Tags: bash, sed, make

I'm new to Makefile and just trying to change a file suffix.
I want to convert files from one format to another eg .mov to .mp4

In bash I would do something like

```
out1 = "${input/mov/mp4}"
```

(is there a way to just use inline Bash syntax in Make?)

anyway it doesn't work. So I found these docs on Text functions
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html

```
$(var:suffix=replacement)
```

so trying to translate that into something I can use...

```
out1 := "${input/mov/mp4}"   ##bash syntax doesnt work
out2 := $(input:suffix=mp4)

check:
    @echo " input: ${input}"
    @echo "  out1: ${out1}"
    @echo "  out2: ${out2}"
```

but it doesn't work, the suffix is untouched

```
$ input=tutorial-v1.mov make check
 input: tutorial-v1.mov
  out1:
  out2: tutorial-v1.mov
```

I've seen other scripts using sed, but just for changing a suffix I just need to get the incantation syntax right.

second question, i dont s'pose there's a nicer way to pass params to a makefile script than have to define named env vars. eg just `make cmd param1 param2` like any other shell script for `$1` ?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the syntax; for your example it would be `$(input:.mov=.mp4)`. See for example [GNU make: 6.3.1 Substitution References](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html#Substitution-Refs)

Comment: hmm that part you are right. but now i can't put the assignment block inside a make command, only once at the top of the file. so it's basically pointless if i need different suffixes :/

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to take both `PARAM1` and `PARAM2` as arguments and then use them in your target:

```bash
check:
    @echo "  input: ${INPUT}"
    @echo " param1: ${PARAM1}"
    @echo " param2: ${PARAM2}"
    @echo "    out: $(INPUT:$(PARAM1)=$(PARAM2))"
```

Here is an example of its usage:

```bash
INPUT=file.mkv PARAM1=.mkv PARAM2=.avi make check
  input: file.mkv
 param1: .mkv
 param2: .avi
    out: file.avi
```

Another option using [file name functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html)

```bash
check:
    @echo " input: ${INPUT}"
    @echo "suffix: ${SUFFIX}"
    @echo "   out: $(addsuffix $(SUFFIX), $(basename $(INPUT)))"
```

Test it like this: `INPUT=file.avi SUFFIX=.mp4 make check`, it should produce the following:

```bash
 input: file.avi
suffix: .mp4
   out: file.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
out1 = $(patsubst %.mov,%.mp4,$(input))
```

Beware: like most stuff in makefiles, it doesn't work if you have spaces in filenames.

If the input is a space-separated list of filenames, so is the output. Each filename is individually converted.